# Calculate within where clause

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Given the following schema

```
var schema = new Schema({
    activeDuration:         {type: Number, required: true},
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

`activeDuration` is a time given in days. How can I create a query which is equal to `SELECT FROM schema WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(createdAt) + (activeDuration * 24 * 60 * 60)) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

So I should receive all objects, which are not "active" anymore (the time where the object was inserted to the database + the given duration is smaller than the current time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, I added a `endsAt` field, which contains a Date(), when the game ends. The query is as easy as:

```
    var query = Game.find({"endsAt": {"$lt": new Date()}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would require an aggregation pipeline that uses **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** operator as it allows you to process otherwise complex logical conditions in a pipeline with the **[`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** operator and uses the special operations **[`$$KEEP`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or **[`$$PRUNE`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** to "remove" the document where the condition was false.

This operation is similar to having a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline that selects the fields in the collection and creates a new field that holds the result from the logical condition query and then a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**, except that **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** does all the computations within a single pipeline stage which can be more efficient.

As for the logical condition, there are [Date Aggregate Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators) as well as [Arithmetic](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#arithmetic-operators) ones to aid with the computations.

Consider the following example pipeline:

```
Model.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                {
                    "$lt": [
                        {
                            "$add": [
                                "$createdAt",
                                { "$multiply": ["$activeDuration", 24 * 60 * 60]}
                            ]
                        },
                        new Date()
                    ]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
], (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
})
```

---

And if going with the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method, then **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)** can be applied as

```
Model.find({ "$where": "(this.createdAt.valueOf() + (this.activeDuration * 24 * 60 * 60)) < +new Date()" })
     .exec((err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data);          
     })
```

Bear in mind the performance costs when using **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)** as the operator calls the JavaScript engine to evaluate JavaScript code on every document and checks the condition for each. It is advisable to combine with indexed queries if you can so that the query may be faster.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Would it be easier and way more performant if I calculate the ending date before saving and save that instead of the duration in days and then just compare the ending date with the current date?

Comment: That would be a lot easier and way more performant with appropriate indexing, that actually is the most recommended way to do. Otherwise with the present schema you would have to go the above route, unfortunately.